# drawing lines instead of a square in Assembler

Tags: assembly, masm, dosbox

instead of displaying a square I have lines when I click on the up and down arrows

And the task is this.

By pressing the F1 key, it draws a square in graphic mode. Using the arrow keys, the square can be moved around the screen. Another key F2 TSR - the program is unloaded.

Please tell me what the problem is? Maybe there is any example of a similar then I will be glad.
compiling the project via DOSBox masm

```
.386
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

square db 13,10, "*******",13,10, "*     *",13,10, "*     *",13,10, "*     *",13,10, "*******",13,10


left_arrow equ 4bh
right_arrow equ 4dh
up_arrow equ 48h
down_arrow equ 50h
f1_key equ 3bh
f2_key equ 3ch

.code
start:

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 13h 
    int 10h

    mov si, offset square
    mov bx, 10
    mov cx, 5

wait_for_key:

    mov ah, 0
    int 16h


    cmp ah, f1_key
    je draw_square

    cmp ah, f2_key
    je exit_program

    cmp ah, left_arrow
    je move_left

    cmp ah, right_arrow
    je move_right

    cmp ah, up_arrow
    je move_up

    cmp ah, down_arrow
    je move_down

    jmp wait_for_key

draw_square:

    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, 0
    mov cx, 5
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset square
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    jmp wait_for_key

move_left:
 
    cmp bx, 10
    jle wait_for_key

    mov ah, 0ch
    mov al, 20 
    mov cx, bx
    mov dx, cx
    dec cx
    mov bx, cx
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0ch
    mov al, 42 ; *
    mov cx, bx
    mov dx, 5
    int 10h

    jmp wait_for_key

move_right:

    cmp bx, 70
    jge wait_for_key

    mov ah, 0ch
    mov al, 20 
    mov cx, bx
    mov dx, cx
    inc cx
    mov bx, cx
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0ch
    mov al, 42 ; *
    mov cx, bx
    mov dx, 5
    int 10h

    jmp wait_for_key

move_up:
    cmp cx, 5
    jle wait_for_key

    mov ah, 0ch
    mov al, 20 
    mov dx, cx
    mov bx, dx
    dec cx
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0ch
    mov al, 42 ; *
    mov cx, bx
    mov dx, cx
    int 10h

    jmp wait_for_key

move_down:
    cmp cx, 20
    jge wait_for_key

    mov ah, 0ch
    mov al, 20
    mov dx, cx
    mov bx, dx
    inc cx
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0ch
    mov al, 42 ; *
    mov cx, bx
    mov dx, cx
    int 10h

    jmp wait_for_key

exit_program:

    mov ah, 0
    int 10h
    mov ah, 4ch
    mov al, 0
    int 21h
    end start
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA9X1.jpg)

instead of displaying a square I have lines when I click on the up and down arrows

Comment: Your `draw_square:`  uses [WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm), which expects `dx`=string `square` **terminated with $ character**.  Also you need not switch to graphic mode 13h when you want to draw squares using ASCII-Art only.

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me what the problem is?

Basically you are confounding between the text video mode and the graphics video mode.
You have a definition of a square made up of asterisk characters. That kind of square would be typical for a text video mode. Now, the task seems to ask you to use a graphics video mode, and you yourself are already drawing single pixels to the graphics screen. But I also notice that you are hoping that an asterisk character would appear from it! Is not going to happen.

### List of troubles

**1** In *draw_square* it is unclear what it is that you want the first DOS call to do.
And the second DOS call (that displays the initial square) depends on the definition of the square to be **$**-terminated:

```
square db 13,10, "*******"
       db 13,10, "*     *"
       db 13,10, "*     *"
       db 13,10, "*     *"
       db 13,10, "*******",13,10,"$"
```

Tip: If the definition of your square contains these codes like carriage return (13) and linefeed (10), it becomes virtually impossible to move the square around on the screen. No matter where you would position the cursor initially, following asterisks will inevitably jump back to the left edge of the screen. You have some re-thinking to do...

**2** In all of the 'movement' codes, you clearly expect to output a character (`mov al, 42 ; *`). So to output a space character `mov al, 20` needs to be `mov al, 20h`.
Sadly none of this matters since the function number in AH is set to 0Ch which is the BIOS function to plot an individual pixel, very much not a whole character!
And what about re-purposing registers on the fly? With `mov bx, 10` `mov cx, 5` (at the top) you had initialized a starting column and row. But then comes `mov cx, bx` that moves the *column* into the *X* parameter, and `mov dx, cx` that wants to move the *row* into the *Y* parameter but can't because the CX register was already overwritten!
A solution for this is to define a couple of variables for the column and the row in the `.data` section:

```
TheCol dw 10
TheRow dw 5
```

and later load the parameters with

```
mov cx, TheCol
mov dx, TheRow
```

**3** In 'exit_program* the BIOS.SetVideoMode call will (try to) setup a random video mode since you forgot to specify AL. Choose mode 3 as in:

```
exit_program:
    mov ax, 0003h
    int 10h
```